# Flutter, Reminder notifications

Tags: flutter, notifications, reminders

I have a list of articles (notes) contained locally in the application. I'd like a notification to appear every 8am and 8pm asking the user to read a randomly selected article. When the user clicks on the notification, it takes him to the article's detail page.

How can I do this?

I've seen the Awesome_notifications or flutter_local_notifications packages but I'm not sure how to configure them to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to schedule a notifications. I know for one Android does support this natively but not really sure for iOS.
Please check [this section](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#scheduling-a-notification) of `flutter_local_notifications` where you can schedule a notification. Then you can add a callback which will open a specific screen of your app when the notification is pressed etc.